# Does the order of columns in a select statement affect query speed?

Tags: mysql

For example, I have a database like this:

```
id | fname | lname | sex | age | tel | cell | address
```

If I do `select cell, fname, address, sex` instead of doing `select fname, sex, cell, address`, will that affect the speed of query, in big tables?

I did a quick check in phpmyadmin and it appeared to be taking same time, but I wanted to double check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That won't make any difference.

However, omitting columns from the `SELECT` clause will make it run faster since it'll send less data over the network.

Comment: @Blue: Omitting columns that you are going to use will also make it faster.  (As will omitting the entire query)

Comment: Didn't he mean omitting the columns and just select all (*) ?

Comment: @mowgli: No; that will make it slower (since it will need to send more data)

Answer (score 1):

It won't affect it the slightest bit.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that will make it run faster is creating indexes on the fields that you will be searching the most.

Comment: Searching means in the `WHERE` (or `ORDER BY`) clause.

Comment: @SLaks, sorry, you are right, this should have been a comment.